# First time translator

Tags: translation, email

If I have no formal training as a writer and I want to translate someone else's book in my home language, what is the best way to get into contact with the author to discuss/recommend this?

Answer (score 4):

Through the author's agent or, if you cannot find them, the book's publisher. If the author has a Facebook profile or webpage and explicitly states that anyone may contact them, you can use that channel as well.

But I think it is unlikely that any professional author will commission someone without any experience.

Answer (score 1):

*Own experience answer:* It is relatively easy to become a translator. Many of my friends did this "job" while studying at school. But it has a drawback: If you have no (or little) experience, you can assume getting "B class" book to translate (or niche type of a book)

First step is obvious: Make a publisher (or publishing house) know that you are willing to translate a book.

Answer (score 1):

You can try traditional authors (contact them through their agents or publishers), but most of them will likely chose a translator with experience.

It may be best for you to try to work your way up through the ranks. You can contact self-published authors, many of whom are more open to non-traditional business plans, and see if they're interested.

You could also translate some excerpts of work in the public domain as a way to demonstrate your skills, and have these available as samples when you contact potential clients.

Comment: Thank you Kate, I have translated a small section of the book with the intention to illustrate my skills.  I am not sure though what you mean by work in the public domain though?

Comment: It's not a good idea to translate or otherwise manipulate books that are still under copyright. The copyright laws will vary depending on where you live, but for many places, copyright extends for 50 years after the author dies. Within this timeframe, the author still "owns" the work and no-one can do anything to it without consent. "Public Domain" works are things that are no longer under copyright, so anyone can do what they want with them.